# FastCGI + Apache: How to map a url to a specific fastcgi binary

Tags: apache-2.2, fastcgi, mod-fcgid

I have written two C++ fastcgi applications (foo and foobar). I am running apache 2.2 (prefork) with **mod_fcgid** on Ubuntu 10.x.

I want to be able to setup apache so that:

http://mywebsite/some/path1?param1=value1&param2=value2

will run the fastcgi app foo

AND

mywebsite/another/path1?param1=value1&param2=value2

will run the fastcgi app foobar

Note: The url above is intentionally invalid (missing the protocol type), since I cant post more than 1 link in this question.

How do I setup apache to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a FcgidWrapper directive with 'virtual' turned on.  This means Apache won't even try to find the "real" file, just call the fcgi script instead.

```
DocumentRoot /whatever

<Directory /whatever/some/path1>
    FcgidWrapper /elsewhere/bin/foo virtual
</Directory>

<Directory /whatever/another/path1>
    FcgidWrapper /elsewhere/bin/foobar virtual
</Directory>
```

Alternatively, you could use mod_rewrite something like this:

```
DocumentRoot /whatever

<Directory /whatever>
    RewriteRule /some/path1 /fcgi/foo 
    RewriteRule /another/path1 /fcgi/foobar
</Directory>

<Directory /whatever/fcgi>
    SetHandler fcgid-script
</Directory>
```